# How do I convert a [u16; 7] sliced array into a *const u16

Tags: rust

I need to convert some array byte data into an *const u16 for the Microsoft windows-rs crate and I stumped how to do this in a safe way which will protect the byte order. I do not want to use any external crates if possible.

```
let logical_drive = [
                    b'\\' as u16,
                    b'\\' as u16,
                    b'.' as u16,
                    b'\\' as u16,
                    b'A' as u16 + 1 as u16,
                    b':' as u16,
                    0,
                ];
let drive:*const u16 = .... conversion code here....
```

I've tried the standard **u16:from_le_bytes(..)** calls however, they only except a [u8] array slice so I'm not sure what the best way is to do this? I've tried the ByteOrder crate but this fails with an error about std:io:Read (which I can't understand even though it is included in my use crates) so please don't mention this as answer.

Comment: _"but this fails with an error about std:io:Read"_ -- What error?

Comment: If you are wanting a zero-terminated array of 16-bit values, you need to end with _two_ u8 0 values.

Comment: The solution is in the duplicate - really easy I didn't understand that Rust stores the array as a sequence of objects, not a pointer like in C. Ther answer is simple: let drive = drive_name.as_ptr();